# How to update a record in MongoDB with 2 different classes without deleting other fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Let's say I have two classes like below:

```
public class Class1 
{
    ....
    public int CityId {get;set;}
    public string CityName {get;set;}
    public ObjectId _id {get;set;}
}

public class Class2 : Class1
{
    public string OrderId {get;set;}
}


collUser.Update(
    Query.EQ("_id", model._id), 
    Update.Replace(model));
```

when I use objects type of `Class2` , update works in a normal way.

but when I use objects type of `Class1` , update deletes `OrderId` field in the record.

I assume it replaces all record ( document) in the collection.

Is there a way to avoid this ? or Is there an easy way than using Update.Set as below ?

```
Update.Set("fieldName",value).Set("fieldName2",value2)
```

I mean , I just want to update the fields if that object (Class1 or Class2) owns the property wthout deleting the rest fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're trying to accomplish this, but it should already work the way you expect. I've done this:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<Class1>("stuff");
var class2 = new Class2 {CityName = "Toronto", OrderId = "12345"};
collection.Save(class2);

var retrieved = collection.FindOne();
collection.Save(retrieved);
retrieved = collection.FindOne();
Console.WriteLine("Object deserialized as type {0}", retrieved.GetClass().Name);
```

The `retrieved` object is actually `Class2` and `OrderId` is preserved (no data loss). I think this is probably the most expected behavior. Mongo accomplishes this by including a [type discriminator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Scalarandhierarchicaldiscriminators). This is basically a hint for itself so it knows what type to deserialize the document to. If you save an `Employee` object into a `Person` typed collection, mongo knows to include the type discriminator because `Employee` is a sub-type of `Person`.

To stay out of trouble, follow one simple rule: strongly type your collections to one single type. If you have a collection that contains `Employees` and `Managers`, you should only ever create `db.GetCollection<Person>("people")`. That way, Mongo can do it's work properly. Once you start doing both `db.GetCollection<Employee>("people")` and `db.GetCollection<Manager>("people")` you get into serious trouble (and the data loss issues you discovered).

If you're still not satisfied with this answer, you might like the idea of [directly updating documents](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-Updatemethod). MongoDB is actually well known for it's ability to quickly update documents. I highly recommend that you look at this section, even if you're satisfied with my first suggestion.

Comment: Isn't the example you're recommending against (`db.GetCollection<Employee>("people")` and `db.GetCollection<Manager>("people")`) one of the benefits of usings MongoDB? I've just recently started using MongoDb and have already ran into this scenario several times but am not quite sure of the best way to handle it.

Comment: @JeremySmith It's a benefit in that yes, MongoDB is highly flexible. However, with flexibility comes a lot of bullets in your feet. I'm just helping you to avoid some problems that you'll likely (and apparently _have_) to run into.